# Pandas group by ID and compute mean of array in cell (value)

Tags: performance, pandas, group-by

My data looks like this (pandas data frame of roughly 10,000,000 rows):

```
ID | Value
```

Where ID is a unique ID per user and is associated with a value, which is an array of 300 dimensions. The same ID can occur multiple times with a different value (array). I would like to, for each unique ID, take the mean of all associated arrays so I end up with a data frame (or dictionary) where one ID only occurs once and has one 300 dimensional array as value (the mean of all arrays previously associated with that ID).

Currently, I loop over the data frame filtering by ID:

```
ifa_vec = dict()

    for uid in df_id_vec['id'].unique():
        ifa_vec[uid] = aggregate_fun(np.matrix(
                           df_id_vec[df_id_vec['id']==uid]['vector'].tolist()))
```

However, naturally, looping is slow and this would take me days. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I know of groupby but have not managed to take the mean over the arrays using it.

Comment: you shouldn't store arrays as elements in your dataframe. dataframes work best with "tidy" data http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html. For this case, I'd just keep your arrays in a dictionary.

Comment: Indeed, but sometimes you cannot choose the format your data comes in.

Comment: sure. and I'm saying that a dictionary of arrays is probably better than a dataframe in this case.

Comment: Transforming the DF to a dict is no issue. However, I struggle to get what I want also with a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner that did the job for me in 20 minutes:

```
val_dict = {k: aggregate_fun(list(v)) for k,v in df_id_d2v.groupby("id")["vector"]}
```